# parbox automatic width calculation

Tags: align, parbox

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\begin{aligned}[t]
  \left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4} \right) \left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{4} \right) 
  &= \left( \frac{4-2}{8} \right) \left( \frac{4-6}{8} \right) 
  & & \parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{Simplify within parenthesis. 
          Simplify within parenthesis. Simplify within parenthesis. 
          Simplify within parenthesis.} \\
  &= \left( \frac{2}{8} \right) \left( \frac{-2}{8} \right) 
  & &\parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{Add within grouping symbols.} \\
  &= \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \left(-\frac{1}{4} \right) 
  & & \parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{Multiply.}\\
  &=  -\frac{1}{16}
\end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

issues the error

[image]

This is primarily due to the `\parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{<content>}.`

Is it possible to create an environment that calculates the remaining `linewidth` for each line independently that the `\parbox` can use?

[image]

---

Consider the MWE using the `linegoal` package suggested by @zarko:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{linegoal}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}    
\left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right) \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{4} \right)
    & = \left( \frac{4 - 2}{8} \right) \left( \frac{4 - 6}{8} \right) 
        &\qquad     
            &   \rlap{\parbox{\linegoal}{\raggedright
                Simplify within parenthesis. Simplify within parenthesis.}}
                                                                    \\[1ex]
    & = \left( \frac{2}{8} \right) \left( \frac{-2}{8} \right)        
        &   &  \rlap{\parbox{\linegoal}{\raggedright
                Add within grouping symbols}}                       \\
    & = \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \left(-\frac{1}{4} \right)         
        &   & \rlap{\parbox{\linegoal}{Multiply}}                   \\
    & = -\frac{1}{16}
    \end{alignat*}
        \begin{alignat*}{2}    
\left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right) \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{4} \right)
    & = \left( \frac{4 - 2}{8} \right) \left( \frac{4 - 6}{8} \right) 
        &\qquad     
            &   \rlap{\parbox{\linegoal}{\raggedright
                Simplify within parenthesis. Simplify within parenthesis.}}
                                                                    \\[1ex]
    & = \left( \frac{2}{8} \right) \left( \frac{-2}{8} \right)        
        &   &  \rlap{\parbox{\linegoal}{\raggedright
                Add within grouping symbols}}                       \\
    & = \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \left(-\frac{1}{4} \right)         
        &   & \rlap{\parbox{\linegoal}{Multiply}}                   \\
    & = -\frac{1}{16}
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

it issues the warnings shown below:

[image]

Is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 2):

With use of `linegoal` (for parboxes widths) and `nccmath` (for local moving equation to the left):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath}  
\usepackage{linegoal}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}[4em]
\[
\begin{aligned}
\left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right) \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{4} \right)
    & = \left( \frac{4 - 2}{8} \right) \left( \frac{4 - 6}{8} \right) 
        &\qquad     
            &   \rlap{\parbox{\linegoal}{\raggedright
                Simplify within parenthesis. Simplify within parenthesis.}}
                                                                    \\[1ex]
    & = \left( \frac{2}{8} \right) \left( \frac{-2}{8} \right)        
        &   &  \rlap{\parbox{\linegoal}{\raggedright
                Add within grouping symbols}}                       \\
    & = \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \left(-\frac{1}{4} \right)         
        &   & \rlap{\parbox{\linegoal}{Multiply}}                   \\
    & = -\frac{1}{16}
    \end{aligned}
\]
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
After first compilation above MWE gives number of warnings, mostly regarding to undefined references. These warnings disappear after second compilation when the parbox get final size:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: It issues the warning `Extended allocation already in use.` Say you copy several instances of the code above right after each other, the `linegoal` package issues several errors/warnings.

Comment: @azetina, I didn't observe such varning.

Comment: I updated my question with your suggested answer. For some reason or the other I get those warnings.

Comment: @azetina, warnings are just warnings. Those warnings doesn't harm result. Linegoal xpect equation numbering which are not present. Meanwhile I a wee bit improve code and result. BTW, if you in edited question use code from my answer, it would be nice to mention this :-)

Comment: I updated my questions with credits to you. BTW you are missing the `\begin{aligned}`

Comment: Don't use the etex package in a current system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, you are right. I check compilation of MWE and observe, that the first compilation gives bunch of errors, which disappear after second (when all data is collected from `.aux` file

Comment: @azetina, thank you for pointing me to missed `\begin{aligned}`. Regarding warnings: With recent version of MikTeX I get your warnings after the first compilation, after second all those warnings disappear (are resolved by compilation). SO I correct my answer again. Final :-)

Comment: @Zarko the code from etex *is* in the kernel. Linegoal shouldn't load etex either, but the package is old and unmaintained. You can avoid the warning from etex with `\makeatletter\disable@package@load{etex}{\let\globcount\newcount\let\globdimen\newdimen}\makeatother` before \documentclass (if you have a current latex),

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you for the tip. I test it and work perfect! I have current LaTeX. It is pity that package is not maintained.

Comment: @Zarko "unmaintained" was perhaps the wrong word. I meant unchanged for 10 years. But you can try to contact the author. It is easy to update the package. He only has to remove etex, and use \newcount/newdimen instead of \globcount/\globdimen.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Now I see that author of `linegoal` is the same as for `tabu`. So, I haven't big hope that author is still active. :-(.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing the width of a `p` column is the main motivation for the tabularx package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
@{}
>{$\displaystyle}r<{$}
@{}
>{$\displaystyle{}}l<{$}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
@{}
}
  \left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4} \right) \left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{4} \right) 
  &= \left( \frac{4-2}{8} \right) \left( \frac{4-6}{8} \right) 
  & Simplify within parenthesis. 
          Simplify within parenthesis. Simplify within parenthesis. 
          Simplify within parenthesis. \\[12pt]
  &= \left( \frac{2}{8} \right) \left( \frac{-2}{8} \right) 
  & Add within grouping symbols. \\[12pt]
  &= \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \left(-\frac{1}{4} \right) 
  & Multiply.\\[12pt]
  &=  -\frac{1}{16}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```